# Should using a DTO mean that I have no other parameters on a method call?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, dto

I'm setting up an application consisting of several WCF services, only one of which can access the database. We'll be passing chunks of data around in DTOs, sometimes in bulk. Because bulk operations assume that one parameter is staying the same, I like the following pattern:

```
private void UpdateItems(long clientId, ItemDto[] items);
```

According to [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html), though, DTOs are defined as objects "that can hold all the data for the call". Does this mean I shouldn't be passing additional data outside of the DTO? Should I really be looking at a pattern like below? Seems to defeat the point of parameters for me.

```
private void UpdateItems(ItemsDto itemsDto);

ItemsDto {
    long ClientId;
    ItemDto[] Items;
}
```

Comment: My example is in C#, and the technologies I'm using are .net but I thought the principal applies to any remote call whatever the language.

Comment: Sure, but what if someone gives you an answer for Lisp? That wouldn't be very relevant right? :)

Comment: It would provide an interesting diversion to the day! :)

Comment: My thinking at the moment is no. The design pattern talks about return types and the usage of a DTO for inbound data is mostly for convenience - there's no *programmatic* expense to having it split over many parameters. The cost of nested DTO structures would outweigh the cost of having two parameters (I'd say there was no cost to 2 parameters, only at 4+ does it get tricky - or if they're all parameters of bool).

Comment: Your `ItemsDto` class is essentially an `ItemsUpdateRequest` in ServiceStack framework or an `ItemsUpdateCommand` in NServiceBus framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Martin Fowler is great, but definitely don't want to do anything "because Fowler said".  What is really needed, is to think about why he gave that advice, and see if those reasons apply for you.

The effect of creating a multi-item DTO here would be to protect yourself from needing to change the interface if you need to change the arguments for batch operations.

For example, if you have to add `clientTimeStamp` to your parameters, it either looks like this:

```
private void UpdateItems(long clientId, DateTimeOffset clientTimeStamp, ItemDto[] items);
```

or this:

```
private void UpdateItems(ItemsDto itemsDto);

ItemsDto {
    long ClientId;
    DateTimeOffset clientTimeStamp;
    ItemDto[] Items;
}
```

Also, notice that you can still use your old interface in a day-to-day way by creating an extension method that packs the arguments into your DTO.

So what's the benefit?  The difference is that if your methods are public and used by many clients, you can maintain backwards compatibility the second way.  It's also a bit easier to change your code, though with VS and resharper, it doesn't actually make much difference.  The cost is a some amount of additional code to write (fairly small in the example, but probably larger in your real codebase).

If you expect to have client code outside your direct control (including clients you write but may not be able to update for some reason), a DTO here is probably worth the cost.  Otherwise, I would leave it alone until next time I wanted to add a parameter there.

Comment: I hadn't thought about backwards-compatibility, thanks for bringing it to my attention (although not a concern for my application, it's good to keep it in mind).